# Best solution to manage Room database version with git

Tags: android, git, version-control, android-room

I'm looking for best practice for the managing room database version while parallel branches are active.

Suppose that in main branch database version is 1. Then in one branch Room Database version will upgrade to 2. in other branches this will happen too and database version might upgrade to 2 or 3 or 4.

[image]

So when branches want to push to the main branch how should we manage them?

For example, in above sample, we have 4 version changing so the last database version should be 5. but branches don't know about others changes to update their migration from them and control their version correctly.

In version control, we can use subversion to control branch types or release version and so on. but by Room database, I don't know how can I control version for various branch.

Because database version just accepts integer numbers so it's confusing to me how to control them in the right way...

Comment: I think this question may be a little overly broad, risking falling into mostly opinion-based answers. I don't think there is a "right way". How do you currently deal with your versionCode, which also is an integer based version or other things that need to be dealt with when the branches are active in parallel? Do you release from your other branches?

Comment: Yes, I release. After releasing the first branch. for other branches, there is conflict in version control.

Comment: @SiamakFerdos is it possible for you to use git tags for assitent? Such as work on multiple branches separately and update the databse version for each time changes, and add tag to record the database version correspondingly.