# How does one best manage database updates with git?

Tags: django, sqlite

I've looked at the two recommended solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58405338/manage-sqlite-database-with-git) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51057159/best-solution-to-manage-room-database-version-with-git), but neither addresses this beginner's confusion about how to handle the database file:

I `push` my (tutorial/practice) code to GitHub, and then `git pull` on PythonAnywhere to deploy it. The file `db.sqlite3` was initially included in .gitignore. However, as the tutorial progressed, changes were made to various models, and new migrations were made locally. The new code gets pushed to GitHub again, so the database needs updating. I've re-pushed `db.sqlite3` to GitHub, then added `db.sqlite3` back to the .gitignore list. But that seems rather inefficient. Is there a better way to handle the `db.sqlite3` file between local development and production (though in this case, it's mock production)? Appreciate some enlightenment on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a file to be tracked by git, ignoring it afterwards will have no effect. To remove file from being tracked by git, use the `git rm --cached <file>` command ([git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---cached)), then commit and push the change. If changes are made to the models, you just apply migrations (which, I assume, are being tracked) -- that enables you to share the code between environments, but separate dev and production databases, which is usually the preferred option.

Comment: Seems like you are confirming that one can keep separate databases for development and production. Then just run parallel migrations after code for models has been altered.  Is that right? (btw I get the part about removing cached files from being tracked by git)

Comment: Yes, running parallel migrations (not terminology that I've heard before, but a good description!) is the normal way to do it.